# Attempting to roll two dice randomly and add the sums till it reaches twentyone

Tags: java, loops, class, methods, program-entry-point

I am trying to code a program that rolls two dice randomly, adds them together, and keeps doing that until it reaches 21. If it reaches 21 it wins but if it hits over 21 it loses.

This is what I have so far, it would be great if I could have some assistance on how to get the dice rolling properly. I am a beginner in java so still trying to understand the syntax.

```
import java.util.Random; 
public class TwentyOne{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dice1;
        int dice2;

        welcome();
        rollingDice(int dice1,int dice2);


    }

    public static void welcome() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Twenty-One! FEELING LUCKY?! goodluck!");

    }

    public static int rollingDice(int dice1, int dice2) {

        dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
        dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6 + 1);
        int sum = dice1 + dice2;
        return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: Call `rollingDice` method in while loop, with terminating condition as per your requirement. Also, no need of passing arguments because you are generating in method itself

Comment: @KamalNayan this is what i changed it too, im getting errors that say i need to add a semicolon after each argument in method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KamalNayan stated above, you need to loop rollingDice until you are at or above 21, and there is no need to pass int agruments in to the rollingDice method since the rolled die values are generated within the scope of that method. Some printing of what's going on also helps to demonstrate what's going on during runtime:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    welcome();

    int total = 0;
    while (total < 21) {
        total += rollingDice();
    };
    System.out.println("Total for all rolls was: " + total);

    if (total == 21) {
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You lose.");
    }

}

public static void welcome() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Twenty-One! FEELING LUCKY?! goodluck!");

}

public static int rollingDice() {

    int dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    int dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    int sum = dice1 + dice2;

    System.out.println(String.format("dice1: %d dice2: %d for a total: %d", dice1, dice2, sum ));

    return sum;

}
```

Here the output from a won game:

```
Welcome to the game of Twenty-One! FEELING LUCKY?! goodluck!
dice1: 4 dice2: 1 for a total: 5
dice1: 1 dice2: 4 for a total: 5
dice1: 1 dice2: 3 for a total: 4
dice1: 6 dice2: 1 for a total: 7
Total for all rolls was: 21
You win!
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I didn't prefer to give source code, so just gave hint, so that he can try by himself, It's good practice for newbies! :)